# Does anybody have a LaTeX CV template similar to this one?

Tags: cv, latex

I am looking for a LaTeX CV template similar to (of possible identical to) this one. Let me know if anybody has it.

[https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~nika/files/Nika_CV.pdf](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/%7Enika/files/Nika_CV.pdf)

Thank you!

Comment: Why don't you contact Prof. Haghtalab directly and ask if they will share their template?

Comment: I thought that's why we had such forums...so that you don't have to cold-email people?

Comment: Hmmm, you just "cold emailed" about 100000 people ;-)

Comment: So did you. Like I said, that is what these forums are meant for. Not the individual's email.

Comment: Just go to Overleaf.  There are many similar templates.

Answer (score 6):

That looks like (or at least very similar to) the kinds of CVs one can generate using the [moderncv package](https://ctan.org/pkg/moderncv?lang=en).  There are various templates available for that package, e.g. [here](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/modern-cv-and-cover-letter-2015-version/sttkgjcysttn).

Comment: The document properties of the PDF file confirm that it was indeed generated with the moderncv package.

Answer (score 3):

This looks like the popular [modern CV package](https://ctan.org/pkg/moderncv?lang=en). It's a bit too popular to make you stand out, if you ask me. But then again, what makes a CV stand out is its content, not its layout.